# How to upload images in background on tabs using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

On some older tablets, while uploading image of size more than 1MB, these uploads can take more than a minute. Is there any way to allow the image upload to take place in the background while allowing the user to move on to next step?  Or is there any other way to ensure the upload will be completed even though user initiates an upload and submits form before upload is finished ?

I'm using ajax upload plugin http://valums.com/ajax-upload/   version 3.5 and back end is PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You need see following tutorial

[Preload Images Using Javascript](http://zainultutorials.blogspot.com/2013/11/preload-images-using-javascript.html)

Comment: I want to upload the images in background. The tutorial is about loading images.